# MongoDB - Structure an array without using key field in Aggregration

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having an issue with making `count` for items returned from an array without assuming or using those fields in my aggregration.

**Data structure looks like this:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "title": "Vanella Icream",
    "contain": "sugar",
    "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Vanella"
      },
      {
        "weight": "10KG"
      },
      {
        "sugar": "15KG"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "title": "Pretzels",
    "contain": "salt",
    "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Wheat"
      },
      {
        "weight": "10KG"
      },
      {
        "sugar": "15KG"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "title": "Rasmalai Icream",
    "contain": "sugar",
    "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Vanella"
      },
      {
        "weight": "15KG"
      },
      {
        "sugar": "12KG"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "title": "Vanella Icream",
    "contain": "sugar",
    "details": [
      {
        "flavour": "Vanella"
      },
      {
        "weight": "15KG"
      },
      {
        "sugar": "12KG"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output I want:**

```
[
  {
    "details": {
      "flavour": {
        "Vanella": 3, //Number of times Vanella present in each document.
        "Wheat": 1,
      },
      "weight": {
        "10KG": 2,
        "15KG": 2
      },
      "sugar": {
        "12KG": 2,
        "15KG": 2
      }
    }
  }
]
```

---

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$details"
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$details",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "flavour": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$flavour",
            "sum": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "flavour": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ],
      "weight": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$weight",
            "sum": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "weight": "$_id"
          }
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "_id": 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "flavour": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$flavour",
                  "as": "w",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$ne": [
                          "$$w.flavour",
                          null
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$let": {
                          "vars": {
                            "o": [
                              [
                                "$$w.flavour",
                                "$$w.sum"
                              ]
                            ]
                          },
                          "in": {
                            "$arrayToObject": "$$o"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      null
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "f",
              "cond": {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$f",
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": {},
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "d": "$$value",
                "p": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$d",
                  "$$p"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "weight": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$weight",
                  "as": "w",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                      {
                        "$ne": [
                          "$$w.weight",
                          null
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$let": {
                          "vars": {
                            "o": [
                              [
                                "$$w.weight",
                                "$$w.sum"
                              ]
                            ]
                          },
                          "in": {
                            "$arrayToObject": "$$o"
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      null
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "as": "f",
              "cond": {
                "$ne": [
                  "$$f",
                  null
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "initialValue": {},
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "d": "$$value",
                "p": "$$this"
              },
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$d",
                  "$$p"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "details": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
])
```

**Here I'm trying to get the `flavour` and `weight` with their count, with manually adding those fields in `$filter` stage. I want to do it without assuming those keys. So, even if there is 20 items present in array `details` it will map those items and shows me output with their counts respectively.**

**I hope you guys understand.**

**Playground**:https://mongoplayground.net/p/j1mzgWvcmvd

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the guy from Mongodb Forum:

Try this out https://mongoplayground.net/p/tfyfpIkHilQ

Comment: If that works for you then try to read and understand the pipeline. If you have questions just ask :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm missing the `count` in group. Great work!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the schema, the thing you want to do is easy, and both those queries are so complicated and slow, even the second that is much smaller has 2 `$unwind` and 3 `$group` with 3 `$arrayToObject` and 8 stages total because of the schema and the schema of the answer.

Don't store data in the keys of the documents, people that are new to MongoDB do those, i was doing it also, but it makes all things harder.(i can't say like never do it but you dont need it here)

Your schema should be something like

```js
{
    "_id": "2",
    "title": "Pretzels",
    "contain": "salt",
    "details": [
      {
        "type" : "flavour",
        "value" : "Wheat"
      },
      {
        "type" : "weight",
        "value" : "10KG"
      },
      {
        "type" : "sugar",
        "value" : "15KG"
      }
    ]
  }
```

[See this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G9NjoUW677l)

Converts your schema, to the new schema and produce the results you
want but without data in keys (the first part you wouldnt need it you would need only the bellow query if you had that schema from start)

Query with the new Schema (no data in keys)

```js
[{"$unwind": { "path": "$details"}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$details"}},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "type": "$type",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      "sum": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$_id","$$ROOT"]}
    }
  },
  {"$project": {"_id": 0}},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$type",
      "values": {
        "$push": {
          "value": "$value",
          "sum": "$sum"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$addFields": {"type": "$_id"}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 0}}
]
```

MongoDB operators are not made to support for data in keys or dynamic keys(uknown keys) (to do it you do complicated things like the above)

If you want to change your schema, either do it with update in the database,
Or take the documents to the application and do it with javascript, and re-insert.

Even if you solve this question in the next one, you will have again problems.